# How can I register a CustomLayoutManager when I create an instance of UITextView from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nslayoutmanager

I want to adapt `CustomeLayoutManager` to `UITextView`.
So I made a subclass (`CustomTextView`) of `UITextView`.

```
final class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        let storage = NSTextStorage()
        let layout = CustomLayoutManager()
        storage.addLayoutManager(layout)
        let container = NSTextContainer()
        container.widthTracksTextView = true
        layout.addTextContainer(container)
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: container)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

`CustomTextView` generated by code works fine.
However, I do not know how to adapt `CustomLayoutManager` when an instance is created from `stroyboard`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your storyboard select your `UITextView`.
2. Select identity inspector (the right pane) and give the class name as
   `CustomTextView`.

Now whenever your storyboard creates an object of `textView` it will be of type `CustomTextView`.

**Edit**

So the issue is reproducible. `init` is not called when you instantaite from storyboard but `init(coder:)` is called. It seems you have to do it programatically.

Comment: Of course I am doing it.
When creating a CustomTextView from the Storyboard, `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called, so it is not possible to adapt the CustomLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom class in storyboard by clicking Identity Inspector from the right panel and typing name of the custom class in 'Class' field.

Also, you need to implement your init code in both init methods.

```
init(frame:) is called whenever you create a view(or subclass) object using UIView(frame:) method.

init(coder:) is called whenever your view(or subclass) is created from the storyboard.
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I understand about instantiation from `storyboard`.
I don't know how to adapt `CustomLayoutManager` when an instance is created from `stroyboard`